# the command "jupyter notebook" refuses to work on my command line on windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This is the exact error it's showing

The Error:
[image: error]

I've tried adding my python interpreter to my systems path but that isn't working too. Besides before I did that my system already recognized my Python installation's path

Python working well:
[image: python code]

Please how do I solve this?

Edit:
Screenshots of the "pip show jupyter" command and the import jupyter; `print(jupyter.__file__)`
[image: The screenshot]

Comment: Have you install `jupyter` on your machine? It looks like the `jupyter.exe` doesn't exist.

Comment: @LironBerger I have. It's still not working

Comment: Hmmm could you add some more info like `pip show jupyter`, and the output of `import jupyter; print(jupyter.__file__)`?

Comment: Also check if you have the `jupyter-notebook` command, it might work for you

Comment: Yay!! Thanks, @LironBerger `jupyter_notebook` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@LironBerger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13201395/liron-berger) for providing the solution which is to use the `jupyter_notebook` command as shown below

[image: The Solution]